# Github ask me to commit files

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Recently I renamed all the packages and removed all the files to another folder in Github.

After that, each time I open up github it asked to commit some files that have no change at all. Basically, it looks like every line of code in a files was deleted and copied again. Those files were edited and committed by others, and I am sure I have synchronized all the files. I am using eclipse to work with it, but I don't think the problem is from IDE.

Can anyone give me a clue about what could possibly cause it?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because when we move files "under the hood" git performs the next steps:

1. Removes the old file
2. Creates new file with the same content

So to sync this changes with remote repository (github in your case) you need just to commit and push them once again.

Comment: Is there any way that I don't have to commit again?

Comment: No. You changed something in the project so it should be reflected in the project history (with `commit` and `push` actions). Otherwise - why do you need `git`?